# creating multiple .exe files using CX_freeze

Tags: python, converters, cx-freeze

I've been working on a little project and I want to convert the files to an executable. the files below are the files that need be included.

```
Btn1 Btn2 Btn3 ...
Scn1 Scn2 Snc3 ...
Button.py
ConSetup.py
Lable.py
PicBox.py
Scenes.py
SimpleGui.py
TextBoxes.py
```

I'm not sure if they all need to be .exe file or if i can put them into the include in the setup file for CX_Freeze. thank you for any help

when I create the build it should run, open a loading screen then open to a main menu, but what actually happens is the program open says a hello message then in the command prompt it just keeps saying:

`'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'Draw'
'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'Tick'`

which is when the file scenes.py tries to open a Scn file that doesn't exist.

Comment: What do you mean *"multiple .exes"*? Isn't the whole point of tools like CX_Freeze to create *single* executables for distribution?

Comment: @jonrsharpe im not sure, i have all the files(the ones listed above) and when i tried to convert it into a .exe and run it it just didnt run. it worked on a similar project that had only the simpleGui.py but not on this one. im trying to put them in the packages file,

Comment: Please edit the question to explain: 1. What you're trying to do. 2. How you tried to do it and what you expected. 3. What happened instead.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok im editing it now ::)

Comment: @wallyk it's not i had a look at it and he is talking about using an installer not actual converting python code into a .exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so i figured it out.
here is the Setup.py file of my program:

```
import cx_Freeze

#executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("SimpleGUI.py", base = "Win32GUI")]
executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("SimpleGUI.py")]
Packages = ["pygame","threading", "time", "socket","ConSetup",
            "Btn0","Btn1","Btn2","Btn3","Btn4","Btn5","Btn6","Btn7","Btn8",
            "ScnGame","ScnMain-Menu","ScnPause-Menu",
            "Button","Label","Scenes","TextBoxes","PicBoxes"]

Include = ["Pictures","Sounds"]

    cx_Freeze.setup(
        name="Side_Scroller",
        options={"build_exe":{"packages":Packages,"include_files":Include}},
        description = "Base Engine for development",
        executables = executables
        )
```

it turns out the issue was a corrupt text file :/

anyway for anyone who want to convert multiple .py files here is the code.

there is 2 Executable variables, the one that's commented out makes it so that the command prompt isn't visible.